# How to properly include libraries in a CMake project

Tags: c++, cmake, dlib

For example, I have a project that looks like this:

```
project/
  subproject/
     CMakeLists.txt
     file1.h

  CMakeLists.txt
  main.cpp
```

project/CMakeLists.txt

```
project(some_project)
add_subdirectory(subproject)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(main ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(main subproject)
```

project/subproject/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(subproject)
add_library(subproject_lib INTERFACE)
target_sources(subproject_lib INTERFACE file1.h)
target_include_directories(subproject_lib INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

project/main.cpp

```
#include <file1.h>

// .. do something
```

Now, when I try to build `project`, I get a `No such file or directory error`.

Another example would be when I try to include dlib. When I do something like

```
add_subdirectory(dlib-19.9)
target_link_libraries(main dlib::dlib)
```

*Which seems to be exactly what is in the dlib's own examples CMakeList.txt*, I get an error.

So, how to include libraries in CMake the right way?

Comment: for `include<>` you'll want to ensure that the target_include_directories(subproject_lib) includes the SYSTEM argument keyword

Comment: @RichardHodges still doesn't work. With `include ""` it works though...

Comment: @RichardHodges or not. It's just the fact that `include ""` searches for the header files in the current directory, not that CMake has correctly invoked `-I` compiler option

Comment: you can also add in subproject/cmakelists.txt: `add_library(subproject::subproject ALIAS subproject)`.
so in main cmake you can use subproject::subproject (same naming if later you choose to pass by a find_package install export/namespace stuff)
Also avoid lib in your name otherwise file become libsubproject_lib.so on linux -_- (or you need to rename the output_library_name...)

Answer (score 2):

Your library is named `subproject_lib`, but you link `main` with `subproject`. I don't know why, but for some reason CMake does not complain if the target does not exist.

Comment: `for some reason CMake does not complain if the target does not exist.` - Non-target arguments for `target_link_libraries` are treated as library names and passed as `-l<name>` options for linker. Linker would detect absent library, but in given case error occures at compile stage, before the linker.